# How to give someone access to a private repository while still allowing me to be the single owner?

Tags: github

I have  project on Github of which I need help with. It started out as a personal project and now evolved to me incorporating a company and hiring someone. How can I give this person access so that they cannot delete anything and only I will be allowed to accept their code changes or not?

This is a personal github account and the repository is private.

Answer (score 1):

Since the account is a personal account, you will be the owner unless you explicitly transfer ownership. Anyone you give access to will be a collaborator. They cannot access repository settings, add or remove collaborators, or delete the repository, for instance.

However, GitHub does not provide fine-grained permission controls for collaborators of repositories from personal accounts. You cannot prevent them from having write access. [This help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account) provides a list of things collaborators can do in the repository.

You can (partly) achieve what you want by [protecting your master branch](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches) and [requiring reviews for pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests).

For more fine-grained access control, you could create an organization account and transfer the repository there, and keep yourself as the sole user with admin permissions. You can then [give your collaborator only read permissions](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization).